# jquery append automatically decodes html encoded string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a string like this:

```
  var b = "<button type='button' onclick='javascript:"+f+"(\""+ encodedString+"\");'> hi</button>"
    //encodedString = "a &quot; &lt;hr&gt; &lt;br&gt;"
```

and after I do something like:

```
$('li').append(b);
```

after this the encodedString becomes decoded and my onclick doesn't work because of the `&quot` becoming `"`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of directly setting the `click` event through html, bind an event listener. `eval(f)` allows you to refer to functions by a string. If possible, I recommend passing a direct reference to the function.

If the function is defined in the global scope, use `window[f]`. Note: This won't work if `f` looks like `Math.round`, because `window["Math.round"] != window["Math"]["round"]`.

```
//f is a string which contains a single function name.
var b = $('<button>').click(function(){
   eval(f)(encodedString); 
});
$('li').append(b);
```

If f is a dynamic variable, which changes (eg, in a loop), wrap the code in an anonymous function:

```
(function(f){
    var b = $('<button>').click(function(){
       f(encodedString); 
    });
    $('li').append(b);
})(eval(f));
```

Comment: my function is not known, i have `f` which is the string function name

Comment: @ChuckNorris Try my answer. `Function("return "+f)` is a method to convert a function name to a function reference. Another method is using `eval(f)` (instead of `Function('return '+f)`).